# joomla4: test the category id

Tags: joomla-4.x, category

I have tried

```
if ($this->item->catid == 12){
return true;
}
```

OR with $article->catid
I put the mentioned code in a module https://joomhelper.com/dbpqnex

Another solution (maybe even more interesting if I make conditions on categories or others) is the excellent sourcerer https://docs4.regularlabs.com/source...rious-examples .
Unfortunately currently despite the advanced settings tested on the plugin, I find myself with a corrupted code when saving as admin in the backoffice with tinyMCE. The setting "Use Joomla text filters" was enabled/disabled in set 0 (related to super admin!)
Code:

> {source} This text should be
> red!
>
> document.write('This text is placed through
> **JavaScript**!');
>
> '; echo 'This text is placed through **PHP**!'; echo
> ''; ?> {/source}

This is another issue, maybe I need to open a new thread?
Regards

Comment: I don't think I will be able to understand/answer your question,  but if _you_ think this post contains multiple questions, please split it into multiple posts.

Comment: see https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28785/get-the-article-id-in-j4-0 !